# error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I'm trying to open the email box using **cordova-plugin-email-composer** but, when I build my project in Android Studio, I get the following error:

```
error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
```

and

```
error: cannot find symbol
public class Provider extends FileProvider {
                              ^
  symbol: class FileProvider
```

Note: it's a capacitor project with:

**capacitor:2.4.7**

**@ionic-native/email-composer:5.36.0**

**cordova-plugin-email-composer:0.9.2**

**ionic:6.17.1**

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Why are you using Cap2 when Cap3 is out. 2) Why use Cap at all. IMO it isn't ready, start over and make it pure Cordova.

Comment: @E.Maggini is there any differences about cordova project and capacitor project while using cordova-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Capacitor uses AndroidX dependencies, while some plugins still use the deprecated android support dependencies.
You can use jetifier to patch the packages, see the troubleshooting guide.

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx cap sync android
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#error-package-androidsupport-does-not-exist